# KOMA class - two-column-text with content and "definitions"

Tags: koma-script, two-column

A lot of (unsuccessful) research later:

I want to use KOMA-class and set a two-column document which contains an outer column for "definitions"/ "additional structure" like shown here:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184885/51132

Is it possible to "fix" the words in outer column to a certain word/paragraph in the main text?

I wonder how this can be done (did not find anything in the internet yet) - thus no MWE so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have got only "short" pieces of text in your additional column, you could use a single column document and then `\marginline{Additional Text Here}` within the text.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\marginline{Lorem!}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac
quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent
et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue
enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula
ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 

Aenean ut \marginline{Gravida Lorem\\see Lorem}gravida lorem. Ut turpis felis,
pulvinar a semper sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna 
consequat sagittis. Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit pharetra tincidunt feugiat
nisl imperdiet. Ut convallis libero in urna ultrices accumsan. Donec sed odio eros. 

Donec viverra mi quis quam pulvinar at malesuada arcu rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque 
penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In rutrum
accumsan ultricies. \marginline{Mauris!}Mauris vitae nisi at sem facilisis semper ac in est.
\end{document}
```

This will put the information in the outer/left margin approximately on-height where the command is issued. The above example will e.g. move the first `\marginline` down and issue a warning.